# How to get .xls data line by line using NPOI in F#

Tags: f#, npoi

I am trying to parse a .xls file and I need to gather all of the data line by line. I am able to call an individual cell.

```
let example =sheet1.GetRow(5).GetCell(1)|> string
```

I am trying to figure out how to use a recursive function to get data from every line from Row 5 till the end of the excel sheet unless there is a row that has no values and then I want to stop. How would I do that? I come from a python background and thinking in a functional language has been a little bit challenging.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Don't use the 14-year old obsolete `xls` format for starters. Use `xlsx` instead. *All* Excel versions since 2006 use `xlsx`, a well defined, XML based format. So do Google Docs and Office Online (obviously). You'll have far, far fewer compatibility headaches if you use `xlsx` *and* far smaller file sizes. An `xlsx` file is a ZIP package containing XML documents following the Open XML specification

Comment: Instead of using NPOI you can use ExcelDataReader and read the data either as records, through an IDataReader or even load all sheets as tables in a Datasheet

Comment: I am parsing a report that is only available in .xls so I am unable to change the format. I am also only wanting certain values from each generated report so I think that ExcelDataReader might not fit it as well as NPOI.

Comment: In the question you say you want to skip the first 5 rows then read until the end or until you encounter an empty line. You can skip by calling Read 5 times. After that, [the IDataReader can be treated as a seq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983087/f-working-with-datareader/2983108) by using a sequence generator - which I just found by googling, I haven't though of using it this way before. You can probably use `IsDbNull` or check for empty fields to detect empty rows in the `while` condition itself

Comment: Have you thought of using [ExcelProvider](https://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/)? Despite some references to Interop in the landing page [the NuGet package depends on ExcelDataProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelProvider), not Interop

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ExcelProvider](https://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/) type provider to read both `xls` and `xlsx` files and treat the data as a sequence. You can skip the first 5 lines then access the rest of the rows the same way you would with a sequence, using the header names as field names. You could use `seq.takeWhile` to stop reading rows if eg the first cell is empty :

```
type TheFile = ExcelFile<"SomeFile.xls">
let file = new TheFile()
let rows = file.Data 
           |> Seq.skip 5 
           |> Seq.takeWhile (fun row->not String.IsNullOrWhitespace row.SomeName)
           |> Seq.map (fun row->row.OrderTotal......0
           ...
```

Fields can be [accessed by position as well](https://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/cells.html)

Comment: What do you mean? The package is in [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelProvider) and supports .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0

Comment: How would you do it if the headers only appear on row 5? The provider does not seem to generate types in this case.